# What does read.Data do?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, kendo-ui

I have the following code in my View (cshtml):

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(model => model.CompetitionSubjectId)
    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:100%" })
    .OptionLabel("choose")
    .DataTextField("SubjectTitle")
    .DataValueField("SubjectID")
    .DataSource(source =>
    {
        source.Read(read =>
        {
            read.Action("GetCascadeSubjects", "Participants")
                .Data("filterSubjects");
        })
        .ServerFiltering(true);
    })
    .Enable(false)
    .AutoBind(false)
    .CascadeFrom("CompetitionBranchId")
```

What does the `Data()` do here?
I reckon it's related to the JS function `filterSubjects`:

```
function filterSubjects() {
    return {
        branches: $("#CompetitionBranchId").val()
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Data()` returns the value from whatever `$("#CompetitionBranchId").val()` is and passes it to the controller method `GetCascadeSubjects`.

My guess is that the controller action should look something like

```
public whatever GetCascadeSubjects(//Sometype branches)
```

The `Read` call is essentially doing the same as when you would pass a parameter to a controller action, such as:

```
read.Action("GetCascadeSubjects", "Participants", new {branches = @Model.Branches})
```